# How to remove certain lines from text file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-re

I am trying to delete specific lines from text files, Which is basically a java code in txt format. I am trying to delete multi-comments from the text, which means script should read the files and delete multi-comments starting with "/*" and end with /* along with "\\" , "package", and "import".

I am using this code, it worked last time for me, but now it is not working

Code

```
import re
import sys
import codecs
txt = "H:\APK_Source_Code_Merged\sstest1.txt"
with open(txt, 'r',encoding= 'utf-8', errors= 'ignore') as fil:
    file = fil.read()

wtalc = re.sub(r"//.*?", '', file, flags=re.S)
wtslc = re.sub(r"/*.*?*/", '', wtalc, flags=re.S)
wtblc = re.sub(r"import.*?", '', wtslc, flags=re.S)
wtblc = re.sub(r"package.*?", '', wtslc, flags=re.S)
print(wtblc)
```

Basically, it is a txt file. The above code perfectly work fine, if i read and remove certains lines from text string then it works fine. But if I read and remove from file, it does not remove any line at all.
sstest1 = "

```
package net.youmi.android.b.a.e.c.g;

import net.youmi.android.b.a.e.a.b.g;
import net.youmi.android.b.a.e.a.b.i;
import net.youmi.android.b.a.e.a.b.l;
import org.json.JSONObject;
//asdasbdaiygd
/* loaded from: classes.dex */
public final class a extends l {
    /* JADX WARN: Failed to parse debug info
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: newPosition > limit: (67103403 > 2726956)
        at java.base/java.nio.Buffer.createPositionException(Buffer.java:318)
        at java.base/java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:293)
        at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.position(ByteBuffer.java:1158)
        at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.position(ByteBuffer.java:263)
        at jadx.plugins.input.dex.sections.SectionReader.absPos(SectionReader.java:82)
        at jadx.plugins.input.dex.sections.debuginfo.DebugInfoParser.process(DebugInfoParser.java:84)
        at jadx.plugins.input.dex.sections.DexCodeReader.getDebugInfo(DexCodeReader.java:118)
        at jadx.core.dex.nodes.MethodNode.getDebugInfo(MethodNode.java:546)
        at jadx.core.dex.visitors.debuginfo.DebugInfoAttachVisitor.visit(DebugInfoAttachVisitor.java:39)
     */
    //Override // net.youmi.android.b.a.e.a.b.l
    protected JSONObject a(i iVar, g gVar) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The above script works perfectly fine if I read and remove certain lines from the text string (from the variable). But if I read and remove it from the file, it does not remove any line at all.

Comment: Could you be a little clearer ? Provide the Java source file on which your script works. And provide the Java source file on which it doesn't.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. No, I am using a python script to read a text file (which happens to be Java source code or it could be any text file ). I want my script to read line by line and remove unwanted lines such as starting with "\\","\* and end with */", "import", "package "

Comment: Ok. So what do you mean by "But if I read and remove from file, it does not remove any line at all" ? What have you removed from the text file that lead to your script not working anymore ?

Answer (score 1):

you have the wrong regex in order to expect `"."` or `"*"` as a string, you need to put a `\` before it:

```
import re
import sys
import codecs
txt = "hi.txt"
with open(txt, 'r',encoding= 'utf-8', errors= 'ignore') as fil:
    file = fil.read()

wtalc = re.sub(r"//.*?\n", '', file)
wtslc = re.sub(r"/\*.*?\*/", '', wtalc, flags=re.S)
x = re.sub(r"import.*?\n", '', wtslc)
x = re.sub(r"package.*?\n", '', x)
print(x)
```

this should the trick.

Comment: Hm...I see a few problems. First, `re.S` allows the dot to match newlines, which doesn't look like a good idea if you want to remove single-line comments. Second, `.*?` will match zero characters if it can, so `re.sub(r"//.*?", '', file, flags=re.S)` will only remove the `//` and leave the rest of the line in place. Third, the `wtblc` variable is overwritten, so `import`s will not be removed.

Comment: Thank you so much. This script partially worked. instead of removing complete line it only removed starting characters such as "//",'import', "package"

Comment: @TimPietzcker Looking at it in depth now makes sense, you are right, i didnt test it out.

Answer (score 0):

You just opened the file in the read mode and, assigned your changed data to a variable. You didn't modify the file yet. Now you write your data to file:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files